# Error on YUI Anim sample

Tags: yui

I'm getting an error when trying to emulate an YUI Anim sample:

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.0.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<script>
   YUI().use('anim-base', function(Y){
      var anim =  new Y.Anim({
         node: '.notice',
         to: {height: 300},
         easing: Y.Easing.backIn
      });

      onClick = function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         anim.run();
      };

      Y.get('.notice').on('click', onClick);
   });
</script>
```

The error is:

> Y.Easing is undefined easing:
>   Y.Easing.backIn\r\n

I was under the impression that YUI loader would retrieve the needed files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer from the YUI Library forum which I will quote:

> YUI will load listed modules a their
>   requirements automatically, however,
>   it will not do any kind of
>   full-fledged feature detection to
>   discover if something else have been
>   used.
>
> You need to change the module list in
>   your use statement from anim-base to
>   anim (or add anim-easing). Then your
>   example will work.
>   -[Stefan](http://twitter.com/stpe)

Answer (score 1):

Adding anim-easing, in this case, seems like the right answer -- use() just the submodules you need.  Stefan is correct, though: You need to list all the submodules that you're depending on directly in your implementation.

Comment: Whoa, reading about myself in third-person on StackOverflow is weird. :) / Stefan